# Why the `pure` of `Applicative Maybe` be defined as `pure = Just` and ignores `Nothing`?

Tags: haskell, applicative

In the [source code of GHC.Base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#), `Applicative Maybe` is defined as:

```
instance Applicative Maybe where
    pure = Just
    ...
```

I am wondering why the pure's definition ignores `Nothing`?

According to this definition, I am expecting that

`pure Nothing` should reduce to `Just Nothing` because `pure = Just` and

```
Prelude> Just Nothing
Just Nothing
```

rather than actually:

```
Prelude> pure Nothing
Nothing
```

Why is this magic? What is my wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It does *not* ignore `Nothing`, but you need to specify for *which* `Applicative` you run the `pure` function, if we run this with `-XTypeApplications`, we can specify the type of the `Applicative`, and then we obtain:

```
$ ghci -XTypeApplications
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> pure @Maybe Nothing
Just Nothing
```

If you do not specify the type, the interpreter will "default" to a certain `Applicative` (in this case the the `IO`) variant, so that means that it will return the value, and the standard behavior of the interpreter is to print the value "wrapped" in the `IO` shell.

The reason why `Applicative` takes `pure = Just`, is because it has to be consistent with the `Functor` instance. This functor instance is defined as:

> ```
> instance Functor Maybe where
>     fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)
>     fmap _ Nothing = Nothing
> ```

Now one of the laws that needs to be satisfied is:

> ```
> fmap f x = pure f <*> x
> ```

So if we would define `pure _ = Nothing`, then this would mean `fmap f x = Nothing <*> x` which means that we "lost information" about `f`. As a result probably the only reasonable solution would be that `fmap` always returns `Nothing`, but that would not make much sense as a functor. It will furthermore violate another constraint at the functor level that says that `fmap id x` should always return `x`.

Answer (score 4):

`pure` is overloaded. When you just type `pure Nothing` on its own, you don’t specify which version of `pure` to call. On its own, it actually has type

```
pure Nothing :: Applicative f => f (Maybe a)
```

If you specifically say you want `Maybe (Maybe a)`, you’ll get what you expect:

```
ghci> pure Nothing :: Maybe (Maybe a)
Just Nothing
```

When you type `pure Nothing` into GHCi, though, it actually chooses to make a `IO (Maybe a)`. This is because GHCi tries to *run* any `IO` action it can. When it executes the action `pure Nothing :: IO (Maybe a)`, then you get back `Nothing`. You can also give a type signature:

```
ghci> pure Nothing :: IO (Maybe a)
Nothing
```

That is, you never called the `pure = Just` version of `pure`. You called a different function, also named `pure`. This is why you got some interesting behavior.